# how to retrieve current location using gps tracker device through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, gps, real-time, tracker

I currently develop a real-time tracking system for my final year project. to track current location I have to use GPS tracker device. but I don't know how can I retrieve current location of the vehicle using javascript and display it's into HTML. can u give me suggestion what GPS tracker can I use to retrieve location using js?

Comment: I would suggest you to read the google maps api https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro

Comment: Welcome. Please review what questions are considered [on-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: i knew about google maps api. but i just wantt data location from gps tracker device. how can i get it?

Comment: @AmirShafri have you managed to achieve this using node js ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access a device's location through the device browser's `Navigator` interface as such:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    do_something(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  });
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available */
}
```

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Comment: thanks, david. but I would like to detect user current location using GPS tracker device.let me illustrate how its flow. GPS tracker sends data location into the database and I want to retrieve its using js/php. but how to make GPS tracker device send its data to a database?

Comment: in this case, the `do_something` would be an ajax call to your backend